# Powershell: apply multiple queries to a foreach on logs

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to get the total data transferred value from multiple log files. The data value is shown under the `total` column in the bytes row.

It is also respectively delimited with a `g`, `m`, `t` or `k` to show gb/mb/tb/kb.

```
           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Bytes :  54.414 g  54.414 g         0         0         0         0
```

Currently I have this script which can go through all the files and extract the value between `Bytes:` and the `g` but I need to be able to add more queries and to the `foreach file and sum them all to one consistent value.

This is what I have currently but only outputs the kb.

```
$pattern = "(?<=.*Bytes :.*)\w.+?(?= g.*)"
$pattern1 = "(?<=.*Bytes :.*)\w.+?(?= m.*)"
$pattern2 = "(?<=.*Bytes :.*)\w.+?(?= k.*)"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\logs" -Filter "BFR*" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-Content "C:\Users\logs\*.log" | where-Object {$_ -match $pattern } | ForEach-Object {
        [double] ($matches[0])
    } | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
} | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content "C:\Users\logs\*.log" | where-Object {$_ -match $pattern1 } | ForEach-Object {
        [double] ($matches[0])
    } | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
} | ForEach-Object {
Get-Content "C:\Users\logs\*.log" | where-Object {$_ -match $pattern2 } | ForEach-Object {
        [double] ($matches[0])
    } | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
}
```

Comment: I've added indenting to your code as it wasn't readable before. We know the pipeline is cool and all, but there are often times when a one-liner isn't the best option. When a single line contains 6 `foreach` and three `Get-Content` you can prob guess that breaking this up is a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility.  (Sorry @JamesC, it's a 1-liner :-)):

```
Get-ChildItem .\LogFolder\*.log |
    ForEach-Object {$totalBytes = 0}{
        Get-Content $_ | Select-String -Pattern "^Bytes\s+:\s+(?<size>\d+\.\d+) (?<units>[tgmk]).*$" | 
            Foreach-Object {
                $size = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value

                switch ($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value)
                {
                    t {$totalbytes += (1tb * $size)}
                    g {$totalbytes += (1gb * $size)}
                    m {$totalbytes += (1mb * $size)}
                    k {$totalbytes += (1kb * $size)}
                }
            }
    } {"Total Bytes: $totalBytes"}
```

Comment: Hey @boxdog I like the method, but on testing the regex pattern its not finding anything in the files. Is there any re-formatting of the pattern you'd suggest to make it work?

Comment: I copied the example you posted straight to a text file and it worked fine. Is your example exactly the same as your real files?  You might need to tweak it for spaces, etc that aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Ah sorry you are right, the log files include a lot more information above that line but this works "^.*Bytes\s+:\s+(?<size>\w+\.\w+) (?<units>[tgmk]).*$"